# отправка сообщения на почту в зависимости от выбранного языка на сайте

Tags: django

Возник вопрос как можно определить с какой странице пришел пост запрос. Есть на сайте два языка. И в зависимости от того с какой страницы пришел запрос хотелось бы формировать разные сообщения.
Сейчас сделал так:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'ru' in str(request):
            mes_mail = "Привет мир!"
            send_mail('Регистрация', mes_mail,
            settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
            mail, 
            fail_silently=False)
        elif 'en' in str(request):
            mes_mail = "Hellow word!"
            send_mail('Registers', mes_mail,
            settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
            mail, 
            fail_silently=False)
```

но это явно нехорошо. Пытался сделать через `from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _`
Но строка `f'Ваша регистрация на  {session_date_visit}  в  {session_time_visit}  подтверждена. спасибо.'`
не переводится на английски.

```
mes = _(f'Ваша регистрация на  {session_date_visit}  в  {session_time_visit}  подтверждена. спасибо.')
```

в файле django.po создается

```
#: .\registers\views.py:127
#, python-brace-format
msgid ""
"Ваша регистрация на  {session_date_visit}  в  {session_time_visit}  "
"подтверждена. спасибо."
msgstr "Your registration for {session_date_visit} at {session_time_visit} "
"confirmed. thanks."
```

но в сообщении не переводится.Если использую обычную строку(`mes =_('привет')`) то все переводится и работает корректно. Как правильно создать перевод для `f-строки` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на данный момент реализовал так

```
mes = str(_('Ваша регистрация на ')) + session_date_visit + str(_(' в ')) + session_date_visit + str(_(' подтверждена. спасибо.'))
```

но все же хотелось бы узнать как реализовать с использованием `f-строки`